# Bad Css Design causing third party menu to mess the images and LI tags

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I am working on website. On adding a 3rd party menu css or Jscript it messes the `<li>` tags of my website.

I read somewhere that my `div` tags should be properly closed in the css. But I am unable to do this after wasting 2 days. I tried to Jscripts menu and also the CSS menus but they all seem to mess up everything.

Here is the link to website.. You can see on default.aspx page the three big images have stopped sliding. Moreover in gallery.aspx page, the images slide as 
I do not use the same menu there.

Website home page link : http://gkainc.somee.com/default.aspx

Gallery link(working): http://gkainc.somee.com/gallery.aspx

I am adding a part of the css file. Please take a look at this.

css can be seen here in the resources of the website.

Comment: Don't like to offsite resources exclusively and don't expect people to go find the files in question. Include the relevant excerpts from those files.

Comment: this is a really common thing on websites and I seriously don't think you need 3rd party stuff...whatever you have there is super simple already. I'd look into css or jquery flyout menu tutorials...drop the 3rd party mess.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that your div `#menuh-container` is huge and has a higher z-index than other elements, meaning it appears above them. You might notice you also can't highlight the search field.

You should give your other elements a higher z-index than the menu container so that they are layered above it, or even better edit your menu container to be smaller (ideally just the size of the actual menu and no bigger).

Hope that helps.

Comment: You were halfway there, but `#menuh-container` has no sizing rules, so the problem was in its children for making it big.  Also, lowering the z-index would cause the submenus to get covered by the images.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is line 16 of animated-menu.css.  You are setting `margin: 40em` to position your menu relative to the left of the screen (why not use `position:absolute;right:0`?) and that is adding a huge margin at the bottom of the menu that makes the menu cover up the images, blocking the click.

If you update this to `margin-left: 40em`, that eliminates the extra margin and corrects the issue.